# Converting a large JSONL (32gb) of Twitter data into a CSV or dataframe (R or Python)

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, twitter

I used the Hydrator app to download a large Twitter dataset. The app converts JSONL to CSV, however, the app dropped a large numbers of cases. I'm not trying to convert the original JSONL into a CSV.

When using R to read the file, I encounter a memory error even when streaming the Tweets in:

```
library(jsonlite)
tweets_df <- stream_in(file("Compiled_Tweets.jsonl"),pagesize = 10000)
#Error:cannot allocate vector of size 5 Kb
```

Using a different method taken from the same thread on Stack Overflow that overcomes the memory issue, I obtain a vector error that I'm unsure how to resolve:

```
file_name<-"Compiled_Tweets.jsonl"
tweet_df<-jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(readLines(file_name, n=100000)),verbose = F)
attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

Following a friend's recommendation, I tried using Pandas as it's supposedly memory efficent however, I'm still getting memory errors when reading the JSONL:

```
df = pd.read_json(r'C:\Users\tomed\Documents\Dissertation\Compiled_Tweets.jsonl')
df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\tomed\Documents\Dissertation\tweet_df.csv', index = None)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-1efdeac4ca20> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_json(r'C:\Users\tomed\Documents\Dissertation\Compiled_Tweets.jsonl')
      2 df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\tomed\Documents\Dissertation\tweet_df.csv', index = None)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    197                 else:
    198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    200 
    201         return cast(F, wrapper)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    294                 )
    295                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 296             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    297 
    298         return wrapper

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines, chunksize, compression, nrows)
    595     )
    596 
--> 597     json_reader = JsonReader(
    598         filepath_or_buffer,
    599         orient=orient,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines, chunksize, compression, nrows)
    678 
    679         data = self._get_data_from_filepath(filepath_or_buffer)
--> 680         self.data = self._preprocess_data(data)
    681 
    682     def _preprocess_data(self, data):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in _preprocess_data(self, data)
    689         """
    690         if hasattr(data, "read") and (not self.chunksize or not self.nrows):
--> 691             data = data.read()
    692         if not hasattr(data, "read") and (self.chunksize or self.nrows):
    693             data = StringIO(data)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    320         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321         data = self.buffer + input
--> 322         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

MemoryError:
```

I tried to use both ijson and bigjson, but configuring them is beyond my technical abilities as I'm new to coding. Is there a way to configure one of scripts above, to either read the JSON so I can make a dataframe, or convert it into a CSV?

Comment: it strikes me you need a streaming API similar to using SAX with large XML documents that won't fit in memory.  Not used it,  but this library offers these features https://pypi.org/project/python-rapidjson/

Comment: 32 GB on a laptop? Hmm...Sounds like you might be trying to squeeze a golf ball through a garden hose. It might be worthwhile to look into using a tool like `Spark` that can work off of disk. You can read `json` into spark, un-nest it via an `explode` function, and then write it out as CSV.  Check out this link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/sql-data-sources-json.html

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a cheat, but it might work for people who might have access to the resources. As this is part of a university project, someone was able to convert the JSON to CSV using the `json2csv.py` utility on a beefy computer.